# MongoDB query in Java - BSONDecoder doesn't understand type : 19 name: h

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to return the results of a MongoDB query but for some reason I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: BSONDecoder doesn't understand type : 19 name: h

How do I resolve this issue? This is the code I have at the moment:

```
public void printData() throws UnknownHostException
{
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("databaseName");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collectionName");

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("status", "A");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

    if (cursor.hasNext()) //The error occurs on this line.
    {
        cursor.next();
        System.out.println("Item: " + cursor.curr());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which driver version? Type 19 is Decimal128 and is a new addition supported in MongoDB 3.4 server. Older drivers may not understand this.

Comment: It is using the mongo-java-driver version 2.12.3.

Comment: OK you are right, I changed the documents within the collection so that they now use `Double` instead of `Decimal128` and the error no longer occurs. Updating the driver version also fixes the issue (in this case I have updated to version 3.5.0). Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, Decimal 128 is a MongoDB 3.4 addition. The only [compatible driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility) is actually the latest release. Either upgrade the driver or change the stored type to something else.